# Client Socket refusing connection and event manager is saying 'Failed to determine the https port for redirect'?

Tags: asp.net-core, sockets, tcpclient

While connecting with the Server TCP IP Port the Client socket connection code which I have used in ASP.Net Core MVC Action call is giving me `Failed to determine the https port for redirect` on the IIS Server while its running perfectly fine on local machine where I had interacted with a Test Server TCP code.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the ForwardedHeadersOptions to forward the two headers in the headers in Startup.ConfigureServices.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddControllers();

      services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
      {
          options.ForwardedHeaders =
              ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
      });
 ...
 ...

  }
```

And

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    } 
}
```

If it not works for you, you also can try to set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT.

**For more details, please refer blow blogs.**

[Resolving Failed to determine the HTTPS port for the redirect](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/failed-to-determine-the-https-port-for-the-redirect/)